# How to redirect user after login to different routes following his type

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I just started using Laravel 5.8 and I want to redirect a user to a different route upon login using gates. I have a column named 'type' in my user table
and I tried this in my LoginController but it's not working.

```
if ( $user->type='admin' ) {// do your margic here
        return redirect()->route('/admin/panelboard');
    }

    return redirect('/home');
    }
```

And this is my gates

```php
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);
    $gate->define('isAdmin', function ($user) {
        return $user->type == 'admin';
    });

    // In case two roles role(['superadmin', 'admin']);
    $gate->define('isProf', function ($user) {
        return $user->type == 'professeur';
    });

    $gate->define('isEtudiant', function ($user) {
        return $user->type == 'etudiant';
    });

    $gate->define('isVisiteur', function ($user) {
        return $user->type == 'visiteur';
    });
}
```

Comment: You're assigning a value to user's type `$user->type='admin'` instead of comparing the two `$user->type == 'admin'`

Answer (score 0):

Check this in documentation, here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates